# Objective-C Base64 decoding returns nil

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, base64

I have downloaded and added the following category into my project: https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

```
NSString *secret = @"7pgj8Dm6";
NSString *decodedSecret = [secret base64DecodedString];
NSLog(@"decoded Secret = %@", decodedSecret);
```

This however, always turns out to be nil. What is happening here ?

Comment: step through it in the debugger.

Comment: I face the same issue. For your particular input 7pgj8Dm6 two different online decoders I used provided two different results :-) so I wonder is that's a valid base64

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helpful to you

```
NSString *decodeString = @"Raja";
```

**Encode String**

```
NSData *encodeData = [decodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [encodeData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
DLog(@"Encode String Value: %@", base64String);
```

**Decode String**

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
DLog(@"Decode String Value: %@", base64String);
```

Thanks

Comment: @MartinE.  what is faced after used one above

Comment: The "Raja" string ? ... Also nil

Answer (score 0):

I've failed to relax iOS native base64 decoder enough with NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters to process jwt payloads
so I had to revert to a 3rdparty MF_Base64Codec

Sadly you might want to consider doing the 3rdparty route
until Apple will have fixed the bug or relaxed the decoder further to
accept what it currently considers crap input

Answer (score 0):

Your input `7pgj8Dm6`is an Invalid base64 encoded string. So the result will be always nil since the method `base64DecodedString` used only for `UTF8 encoding`.

> As of iOS 7 and Mac OS 10.9, [this library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64) is not longer needed.

You can use `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:`

The default implementation of this method will reject non-alphabet characters, including line break characters. To support different encodings and ignore non-alphabet characters, specify an options value of `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters`.